# Python Imports Explained

Tags: python, python-import

Having a hard time wrapping my head around Python imports. I've read the difference between import X and from X import * here- http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm but I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between import "module" and from "module" import *. Especially since the effbot article recommends sticking with import "module" and that's not working here.

This code

```
import csv
import time
import datetime

startdate = time.strptime('31-Dec-50', "%d-%b-%y")
enddate = time.strptime('1-Jan-00', "%d-%b-%y")

with open('Classroom Utilization.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        file = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in file:
            checkstartdate = time.strptime(row['startdate'], "%d-%b-%y")
            checkenddate = time.strptime(row['enddate'], "%d-%b-%y")

            if checkstartdate < startdate:
                    startdate = checkstartdate
            if checkenddate > enddate:
                    enddate = checkenddate

print time.strftime("%d-%b-%y", startdate)
print time.strftime("%d-%b-%y", enddate)

print "pre convert: " + str(startdate)
print "pre convert: " + str(enddate)

startdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(startdate))
enddate = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(enddate))

print "post convert: " + str(startdate)
print "post convert: " + str(enddate)

print '%s/%s/%s' % (startdate.month, startdate.day , startdate.year)
```

returns this error

```
File "deconflict.py", line 29, in <module>
    startdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(startdate))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'
```

From the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime), the datetime object in the datetime module has the method fromtimestamp, but the import doesn't let me use it.

On the other hand, using from module import * fixes all the problems. Although I don't understand why with from time import * allows me to just use strptime(), but with from datetime import * I still have to say datetime.fromtimestamp.

```
import csv
from time import *
from datetime import *

startdate = strptime('31-Dec-50', "%d-%b-%y")
enddate = strptime('1-Jan-00', "%d-%b-%y")

with open('Classroom Utilization.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        file = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in file:
            checkstartdate = strptime(row['startdate'], "%d-%b-%y")
            checkenddate = strptime(row['enddate'], "%d-%b-%y")

            if checkstartdate < startdate:
                    startdate = checkstartdate
            if checkenddate > enddate:
                    enddate = checkenddate

print strftime("%d-%b-%y", startdate)
print strftime("%d-%b-%y", enddate)

print "pre convert: " + str(startdate)
print "pre convert: " + str(enddate)

startdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(startdate))
enddate = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(enddate))

print "post convert: " + str(startdate)
print "post convert: " + str(enddate)

print '%s/%s/%s' % (startdate.month, startdate.day , startdate.year)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case, the `datetime` *module* has a `datetime` *class*. It's confusing, since they have the same name. When you do `import datetime`, what you get is a module named `datetime`. To access members of that module (such as the `datetime` class), you need to fully qualify it (eg: `datetime.datetime`)

For example:

```
import datetime
startdate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(startdate))
```

When you do `from datetime import *`, the thing referenced by `datetime` is not the module, but the class of the same name. You get the same object as if you did `from datetime import datetime` which means "from the datetime *module* import the datetime *class*"

Answer (score 2):

the datetime module has a datetime class within it. This is how you would use it

```
from datetime import *
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp
```

the time module doesn't have a time class and exposes its methods directly.